# UITableView jitter when inserting rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When the user scrolls to the bottom of the `UITableView`, I call a web service to get another set of 10 rows. I insert the rows using:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToAdd withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

The issue I am experiencing is that when it inserts the content, the UI jitters and sets my scroll view up ~4 rows (half the screen). I end up having to scroll back down the ~4 rows to see the new content.
I am trying to achieve the look where the view does not change and you just see it append the new rows to the bottom (like how Instagram and Facebook does it)

Comment: I believe being/end updates is only required when you're making several insertions and deletions simultaneously. Not sure if this is what is causing your problem though.

Comment: Is the height of all cells fixed (always the same)? If not, how do you handle variable height? Are there any changes to previous rows when you insert new rows?

Comment: do you have automatic sized cells ? because once the cells go above the tableview and it estimates again , there will be issues on reload ... one solution for this would be to keep the sizes in a array and use those dimensions if you know for sure those **IndexPath**s won't change anymore.

Comment: @jcaron No, the heights alternate lets between lets say Height and 2xHeight. No, I do not make any changes to the previous rows. I use `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 214.0f;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`

Comment: @RaicaDumitruCristian that does sound like it might be the issue as jcaron was mentioning

Comment: @Alan yes, but you don't explicitly make changes to the height. but as i see from your answer your cells get initialized with the height 214. But the actual size is 214 ? because if it is bigger, then this is your problem. When you reload he recalculates all the cells above at 214 height. and the content moves up. If you scroll down, does the table jump at every cell ? LE (scroll down, as in try to view the cells above tableview)

Comment: tried reloadData instead of insertRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation: for testing?

Comment: @RaicaDumitruCristian It seems to scroll fine up and down. This jumping only occurs on inserting rows. It looks like the heights being automatically set is alternating 121 and 251.

Comment: Yea it looks like this is the issue. When I turn off AutomaticDimension and set the height to a static 251, there is no issue.

Comment: @RaicaDumitruCristian Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. If you want to post an answer, I'll be happy to check mark it.

Comment: @Alan i'm glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i see from your answer your cells get initialized with the height 214. But the actual size is 214 ? because if it is bigger, then this is your problem. When you reload he recalculates all the cells above at 214 height. and the content moves up. If you scroll down, does the table jump at every cell ? LE (scroll down, as in try to view the cells above tableview)